# Artifactory Eclipse RCP in Jenkins Build Error

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, artifactory, tycho

I'm trying to use Tycho Maven to build an RCP application in Jenkins. The build works fine from the command line and even in Jenkins (when I use the appropriated settings.xml file to resolve the artifacts using my Artifactory server) but as soon as I enable the Artifactory plugin in the job configuration I get the following error:

```
Checking out Revision 6e23fe54a2fef24e13e4c08551c132c7932392a9 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 6e23fe54a2fef24e13e4c08551c132c7932392a9
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.8.2
Artifactory integration is enabled
[ConsolePOMlss] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK1.8/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven -DbuildInfoConfig.propertiesFile=/tmp/buildInfo1521811850289716273.properties -Dm3plugin.lib=/var/lib/jenkins/cache/artifactory-plugin/2.8.2 -Dclassworlds.conf=/tmp/classworlds2157837551391886905conf -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean verify
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Scanning for projects...
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.jdom/.polyglot.build.properties
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.clientserverkit/.polyglot.build.properties
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.items.datastoreclasses/.polyglot.build.properties
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.ui.utilities/.polyglot.build.properties
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.ui.debug/.polyglot.build.properties
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BigItem/ConsolePOMlss/bundles/com.acme.items.console/.polyglot.build.properties
[main] ERROR org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - Failed while enforcing Artifactory artifact resolver
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseArtifactResolver
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:237)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.enforceArtifactoryResolver(ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.java:71)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.contextualize(ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.contextualize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Pending.activate(BeanScheduler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.EntrySetAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntrySetAdapter.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryEventDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRepositoryEventDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.artifactResolving(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.resolveExtensionArtifacts(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:908)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupExtensionsRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:839)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled(DefaultModelBuildingListener.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire(ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1295)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:441)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:421)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:620)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:411)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 61 more
```

I'm using:

- Jenkins 2.32.1
- Artifactory Plig-in 2.8.2
- Tycho 0.26.0
- maven 3.3.9

Some more information ... This is the point where my build in Jenkins with **Maven-3-Artifactory** enabled an the build with **Maven-3-Artifactory** differ. It seems that it doesn't have to do with my sources but a bug in the plugin.

With Maven-3-Artifactory Integration **enabled**:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Scanning for projects...
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - Enforcing Artifactory artifact resolver
[main] ERROR org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - Failed while enforcing Artifactory artifact resolver
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseArtifactResolver
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:237)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.enforceArtifactoryResolver(ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.java:71)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.contextualize(ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.contextualize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Pending.activate(BeanScheduler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
```

And with Maven-3-Artifactory Integration **disabled**:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
/home/jmorcate/bundles/com.acme.packageA/.polyglot.build.properties
/home/jmorcate/bundles/com.acme.packageB/.polyglot.build.properties
/home/jmorcate/bundles/com.acme.utilities/.polyglot.build.properties
/home/jmorcate/bundles/com.acme.ui.debug/.polyglot.build.properties
/home/jmorcate/bundles/nato.ncia.sssb.cloud22.console/.polyglot.build.properties
/home/jmorcate/features/com.acme.feature/.polyglot.build.properties
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=81, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=40, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=4, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=80, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=178, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue due to takari extentions in "${project.basedir}/.mvn/extensions.xml" folder.  Everything works after extensions were disabled.

Despite you did not specify that i am sure that you use it.

Comment: Right Valery! In fact it's a pom-less build so I need the extension.xml. I'll take a look next week at work. Thank you very much.